# Vue mobile app project with visual studio 2017

Tags: javascript, android, html, visual-studio, vue.js

I would like too create a vue mobile app project with visual studio 2017.

Im not intressted with `xaml` i want to use `html` and `javascript` only.

I notice when i create new project that there is `basic vue web application` in visual studio 2017.

But i want to have a mobile app instead, that mean i would also like to debug this with my samsung.

Dose anyone know how to setup this in visual studio and what type of project i should use.

Answer (score 0):

My top two though are:
- Vue-NativeScript
- Quasar Framework

Vue-NativeScript is nice because 100% of dependencies you use will work when it's compiled to mobile. Also, with it you have 100% direct access to all iOS and Android APIs.

Quasar Framework is my favorite. You can build Responsive Single Page Apps, Server-side Render Apps, Progressive Web Apps, Hybrid Mobile Apps & Electron Apps, all using the same codebase.

Definitely do as much research as possible before you dive into these two and make sure you're familiar with the cost/benefit if you decide to go with one of them. Good luck!

Comment: hmm but i really want it in visual studio, so i could build, run ,debug and publish in visual studio 2017. I started looking `cordova` it can be somthing.